# WordPress API - sign-up to multiple Multisites from one single form

Tags: multisite, advanced-custom-fields, rest-api, api, multisite-user-management

Creating a sign-up form network multisite registration where the user can register to three different Multisites at the same time (and automatically new sub-sites are generated In three different domains and different WordPress networks). Is this possible using the WordPress Rest API to send this request to the other two networks? Can this process be done with any plugin? In terms of development time and complexity? Thanks in advance

Comment: This might work? https://wordpress.org/plugins/network-subsite-user-registration/

Comment: Thanks but this plugin seems to be only valid for registration on the same network. I need to create a registration form to create a sub-site where the users can select three option ( checkbox -- 1- or 2 or 3 - can register to one, two or all together) (websites that are completely different multi-sites networks and will create three different sub-sites in each network). I think the use of Wordpress REST API is necessary. Thanks